# How do I make my spam site rank well and not get penalized?

Tags: seo, spam, ranking, penalty, spamming

This question may sound really stupid, but it's actually legit.

As the web has gotten more spam-proof over the years (CAPTCHAs, spam filters, search engine algorithms, etc.), there's not much room left for spammers to spam without worry that their content will be deleted. That's why I created a website where users are *encouraged* to post spam, promote spam links, advertise spam websites, and comment on other users' spam.

The only problem is, if my website is *supposed* to be spammy, how am I going to rank well on search engines?

---

To clarify, this website is intentionally filled with spam. It is literally a spam city. This is not about backlinks from spam sites or deleting user-generated spam content.

Comment: You're not. You can point to your spammy site from another site that isn't, but that's not going to bode well for that site. Seems like a futile exercise, unless you plan on just link generated or word-of-mouth based traffic...

Comment: What kind of spam are we talking about? Do you invite spam bots to post their advertisements? Could you explain your motivation for this, i.e.,do you hope to accomplish something specific?

Comment: I don't invite spambots, but there aren't any rules against them.

Comment: Google believes is your responsible to administrate your site, if you fail to do so, then Google has the right to take action, that's Google's stance on the matter, so the answer is you won't rank a site that has been spammed with comments and other bot generated junk. Get rid of that junk, and then Google may start to rank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way that most crawlers work they will detect your site as being spammy and penalize it. It will most likely still appear in the search engine indexes as long as it isn't reported as a malicious site but you will not rank very highly at all unless you have very specific niche keywords which other sites do not use or someone does a search specifically for your site.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to *expose* how spam is being employed and help the visitor recognize and learn to identify spam, that may be a different story. Even if your good intentions are clearly spelled out to your visitor(s) Google may still overlook that fact and penalize you based on the links and content you provide.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you mean you are going to prevent from being spam, the only way is your backlink (link building) quality in the first stage!

Do not buy any spammy backlink. There are lots of websites selling backlink for only 10$! Just do not buy from these website cause most of the links are on the spammy website!

Driving traffic on your website is a good idea too.

Use schema markups for the rating and AMP for the mobile devices, it will help you too.

And afterall, track your website links with Webmaster Tools.

I hope it helps!